# how to get the "enter"key using Tapplicationevent component

Tags: delphi

i want to get the "enter"key message when the "enter"key pressed.i tried using Tapplicationevent component.the code is

```
procedure TForm6.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
    if   Msg.message=WM_KeyDown   then
      if   msg.wParam=Windows.VK_RETURN   then
      begin
          Button1.Click();
          handled:=True;
      end;
end;
```

but it can't work.how to improve ? thanks

Comment: Do you just want to see it when the key is pressed on a specific form or across the entire application? The OnKeyDown, OnKeyUp, or OnKeyPress event on the form might be a better fit (be sure to set the KeyPreview property correctly), depending on your use case.

Comment: I'm also reading into your code above that you want a specific button clicked when the Enter key is pressed on TForm6. Have you looked at what the TButton.Default property does?

Comment: The top-level window of `TApplcation` is not visible on the screen and very unlikely to receive keyboard input. Your code is correct but your approach to the problem probably isn't. What you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Free OnMessage event is fired for every queued message received by the thread.

Comment: @FreeConsulting the `TApplication.OnMessage` event (and by extension, the `TApplicationEvents.OnMessage` event) is fired for every message that is retrieved from the main message queue and before it is processed and dispatched to the rest of the app. That includes keyboard and mouse messages.

Comment: thanks comment for Sam M,  Free Consulting,Sam M,David Heffernan and @Remy Lebeau. i'v create a new project and it work.i don't know why .this new project is smaller one(4 form). i will try more later. thanks experts a lot.